# Adding 'onblur' to a validation form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, onblur

I am quite new to javascript and am trying to make a validation form that validates once you click out of the input field. I have been trying out many different ways to add on blur to a current validating form which I have created.

How could I add on blur to my validation form? Thanks :)

```
function addFormValidation(theForm) {

    if (theForm === null || theForm.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'FORM') {
        throw new Error("expected first parameter to addFormValidation to be a FORM.");
    }

    theForm.noValidate = true;

    theForm.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
        var isError = false;

        var elements = this.elements;
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
            if (! isFieldValid(elements[i])) {
                isError = true;
            }
        }

        if (isError) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    function isFieldValid(field) {
        var errorMessage = "";

        if (! needsToBeValidated(field)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (field.id.length === 0 || field.name.length === 0) {
            console.error("error: ", field);
            throw new Error("found a field that is missing an id and/or name attribute. name should be there. id is required for determining the field's error message element.");
        }

        field.classList.remove('invalid');

        var errorSpan = document.querySelector('#' + field.id + '-error');

        if (errorSpan === null) {
            console.error("error: ", field);
            throw new Error("could not find the '#" + field.id + "-error' element. It's needed for error messages if #" + field.id + " is ever invalid.");
        }

        errorSpan.classList.remove('danger');
        errorSpan.innerHTML = "";

        if (field.minLength > 0 && field.value.length < field.minLength) {
            errorMessage = "Must be " + field.minLength + " or more characters long.";
        }

        if (field.type === "email" && !isEmail(field.value)) {
            errorMessage = "This should be a valid email address.";
        }

        if (field.required && field.value.trim() === "") {
            errorMessage = "This field is required.";
        }

        if (errorMessage !== "") {
            field.classList.add('invalid');

            errorSpan.classList.add('danger');
            errorSpan.innerHTML = errorMessage;
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    function needsToBeValidated(field) {
        return ['submit', 'reset', 'button', 'hidden', 'fieldset'].indexOf(field.type) === -1;
    }

    function isEmail(input) {
        return input.match(/^([a-z0-9_.\-+]+)@([\da-z.\-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,})$/);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="content">
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="success.html">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="" onblur="addFormValidation('firstname');"/>
    <span id="firstname-error"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" onblur="addFormValidation('lastname');">
    <span id= "lastname-error" ></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
    <span id="email-error"></span>
  </div>

              <div class="form-group">
    <label for="flight">Flight</label>
    <select name="flight" id="flight" required>
    <option value="">Please select a flight</option>
    <option value="1">Fixed Wing</option>
    <option value="2">Helicopter</option>
    <option value="3">Glider</option>
    </select>
    <span id="flight-error"></span>
  </div>



        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <input id="date" type="date" name="date" required>
    <span id="date-error"></span>
  </div>

        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="time">Time</label>
    <input id="time" type="time" name="time" required>
    <span id="time-error"></span>
  </div>

        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="duration">Duration</label>

    <select name="duration" id="duration" required>
    <option value="">Please select your desired duration</option>
    <option value="1">1 Hour</option>
    <option value="2">2 Hours</option>
    <option value="3">3 Hours</option>
    <option value="4">4 Hours</option>
    <option value="5">5 Hours</option>
    </select>
    <span id="duration-error"></span>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>

</form>
</div>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    addFormValidation(document.querySelector('#contact-form'));
  });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dLz5w2tz/

Comment: That is some HTML and some Javascript, but I think you forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend not using element attributes (onblur) for javascript event execution; instead you can add the listener to your javascript code.

I've done the following to your code:

1. Remove "onblur" attributes
2. Add code in your JS to listen to blur events on the entire form (all elements).

JS snipped

```
theForm.addEventListener('blur', function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
}, true);
```

Updated JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dLz5w2tz/1/

Note:
addEventListner takes 3 parameters - 
1. "event"
2. function to execute
3. boolean - should it bubble/propagate the event upwards.

So basically, in this code, the event takes place on the form element (input) and bubbles up to the form itself. You can verify this by looking at the event variable (evt).

Comment: From what you have done in the jsfiddle, should it be working?

Comment: Yes - check your console logs while you focus/blur elements in the form. You'll see the evt.

Comment: Minor correction, Third parameter in addEventListener is essentially not for bubbling its for capturing event if you give it false your event will still bubble. That is default behavior. To stop this default behavior we use stopPropagation.